# Safari mobile blurry when scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, safari

i have a panel that should be drawn floating over the normal html page.
This object is dynamically created on DOMloaded event and scaled to fit current screen resolution depending on the zoom level of page.
In order to obtain that we have to scale the element, because we fix the width and height.
The scale amount in not mobile friendly website is always bigger than 1. It seems to work in all browsers except for Safari mobile, in which the floating panel is blurry.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: The browsers you test are all on an iPhone?

Comment: On all the other browsers work well.

Comment: Yes, but do you test them on an iPhone, on the desktop or on another mobile device?

Comment: I'm testing over several android's device and desktop browsers. The problem raises only in Safari on iPhone.

Comment: Does it raise in Firefox/Chrome on iPhone?

Comment: The problem raises also in Chrome on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

It is the device, not the browser. iPhones have retina displays, which, in plain words, means that the pixels are doubled. Fonts, borders and other CSS styles scale up fine, but images are stretched, that's the reason your image appears blurred.

**The simplest way to fix this is to use a bigger image**

Of course this has the drawback that well... you will be using a bigger image for all devices/browsers even if you don't need one. Of course, there are many other ways to handle this.

Here is a place to start:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/towards-retina-web/

http://www.mightybytes.com/blog/make-retina-images-website/